# Saving and dowloading files with java (HomeMade Cloud)

Tags: java, file, file-upload, download, cloud

Hello :) I'm here because i want to create my own cloud server using Java Spring. In this cloud i want to save files like .docx, .mp4, .exe saving them on a HDD. (Later i want to run this server on a Raspberry). I want to be able to open and download this files on any type of device and from anywhere

For that i gonna user Java 1.8 with Spring for the backend.

So my answer is : which framework can i use to do that, to save my files on a HDD and download this files on my device from this same hdd ? i know for example with NodeJs there is express-fileupload. There is something similar in java ?

Thank you ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you use case just use drive, don't reinvent the wheel - google cloud, dropbox, s3, etc.

Also, it's not correct to say that you want to "create your own cloud" - you just want to create a storage system.

Comment: In fact, no, i want to make my own google cloud or dropbox. Obviously i can use a hdd and that's it, but for the fun and the challenge i want to create a cloud.

Comment: I don't understand where do you want to save those files - in your hdd or online (and just make ui).  If you want to make a server from your own computer - you can connect hdd, and make your computer a server (ftp or s3).

Comment: If you just want to make the ui, you can upload to an online s3 (like aws), and just make an app to download those files.

Comment: Hi, i want to save my files in my hdd, and make this hdd accessible from everywhere. For that, I want to create a Java server, but i don't know which framework use to make the API Request (or maybe i don't need framework , and i can do that just with java, that the question :)